# How much larger should a bga pad be than the ball itself?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I've never had to do the layout for a board involving a BGA part until now.  I'm curious what the rule of thumb is on oversizing the pad for the ball.  What size pad should I use if a part has balls that are .35 mm diameter with .65mm spacing between centers?  Is there a general rule of thumb for how much to oversize the pad on a bga part?

Edit:

Here's a screen shot of the part from the datasheet

[image]

Comment: Not too large to have enough solder mask.

Comment: Can you clarify?  I saw on this page: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/eda/looking-for-cheap-pcb-manufacturer-service-for-1mm-pitch-bga-prototyping/ that the recommended pad size is actually smaller than the nominal ball size.  About half way down somebody states .6x.

Comment: The land is usually *smaller* than the ball on a BGA of that pitch or coarser. Maybe 0.29mm. I use the IPC-compliant wizard on EDA software, which uses a lot more information than you've given, so this is not an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info @SpehroPefhany.  What other info is required?  Unfortunately I'm using eagle, which doesn't (so far as I know) have a wizard to help create the package.

Comment: You will also need to take into account reasonable trace width, pad to trace space, via pad size and via hole size. You will want to look at the capabilities of the PCB manufacturer. It is also worthwhile to spend some time planning your signal breakout paths.

Comment: What does the manufacturer recommend?

Comment: The IC manufacturer has "no recommendations."  I'm trying to see if I can get this done using oshpark's service which has 5/5 trace space and 10 mil drill min with 4 mil annular ring min.

Comment: It surprises me that there is no recommended land pattern in the datasheet. What BGA part/manufacturer is it?

Comment: @TomCarpenter you and me both.  It's an imaging sensor from Aptina.  Their documentation leaves much to be desired.

Comment: NXP (different manufacturer, but gives some idea) recommend a 0.25mm diameter pad, 0.37mm diameter solder mask window, and 0.254mm paste diameter for their 0.65mm pitch BGAs. [Reference](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10778.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Intel's BGA packaging guide has some good guidelines:

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/packaging-databooks/packaging-chapter-14-databook.pdf

Check out pages 17 through 20.

They recommend a 20 mil pad with a 24 mil mask opening, for 2mil annular ring.